# Move first <li> item to last without using order as list is dynamic using css

Tags: html, css

I have unordered list with list items as follows. I don't want to use `order` here as my list may be dynamic with more or less items.

Example:

```
<ul class='test'>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Now i want to move the first list item to last without using order property.

Comment: Do you want to move only one item to last? Please add more context

Comment: I know you're aiming not to use it and it may be a little hacky, but I think a reasonable solution is definitely achievable with the `order` property (despite the dynamic list)

Comment: You'll need to explain your use case for this in order to obtain useful help. Personally I'd opt for JavaScript, but that doesn't seem to be what you'd prefer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why you cannot use `order` even if your list is dynamic - you don't need to add an order for each item - if they share an order, they will be listed as they come in the dom - below all `li` will be ordered normally using `1` and the first-child will be moved to the end using `2`

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.test li {
  order: 1;
}

.test li:first-child {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul class='test'>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<ul class='test'>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
<ul class='test'>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is so un-intuitive, but a great answer

Answer (score 2):

You would need to append using JS if you do not want to use CSS order

```js
const list = document.querySelector(".test");
list.appendChild(list.querySelector("li"))
```

```html
<ul class='test'>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

More than one list with class list:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("ul.test")
  .forEach(list => list.appendChild(list.querySelector("li")))
```

```html
<ul class='test'>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
<ul class='test'>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```